# Get_post_meta() won't return value

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, loop, links

Ok guys... I'm sure this is going to be a really easy answer. I'm a complete noob at this.

I have a custom field that is supposed to return a link. For some reason, it just redirects me back to my site homepage. I'm really new to Wordpress so I'm not sure what's going on but I've scoured Google and this is what I've got:

```
 href="<?php get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'ramco-videos-link', true);
```

Why won't it return the link in the custom field?

Comment: `get_post_meta` won't print anything. Use `echo get_post_meta`.

Answer (score 4):

`get_post_meta()` only returns the output, but does not print it. You have to use either `echo` or `the_meta()` to print the actual output.

```
 href="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'ramco-videos-link', true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ramco-videos-link', true); ?>
```

Make sure you have the closing PHP tag in there.